# Flutter null safety, package doesn't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

whenever I run "flutter pub get", I get this error

```
Resolving dependencies... 
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.6.

Because background_locator_2 depends on location_permissions >=1.0.1 <4.0.0 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

I updated my pubspec.yaml file to this

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.12.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^2.1.0
  location_permissions: ^3.0.0
```

but that didn't solvee my problem

Comment: comment location_permissions

Answer (score 1):

The error is explicit.
The package that you are using called **background_locator_2** has a dependency with a version that doesn't follow the **null safety** guidelines.

Importing a different version of **location_permissions** in your project does nothing to the original relation (package>dependency).

Check which version of **background_locator_2** you are using.
According to [pub.dev docs](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator_2), that dependency doesn't exist on the most recent release (2.0.6)